# Why do `Shape* rect = Rectangle(..)` and `Shape* rect = &Rectangle(..)` not compile, but `Shape* rect = new Rectangle(..)` does?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have an abstract class `Shape` and a subclass `Rectangle`.

I'm trying to create a `Shape*`, and assign it a `Rectangle` instance (actually, the *address* of an instance since this is a pointer..?).

I tried this:

```
Shape* rect = Rectangle(5, 5);
```

And got the error:

```
cannot convert from 'Rectangle' to 'Shape*' in initialization
```

I then tried this:

```
Shape* rect = &Rectangle(5, 5);
```

And received the error:

```
taking address of temporary
```

Finally, I tried the following, and it worked:

```
Shape* rect = new Rectangle(5, 5);
```

What I want to understand, is why did this work and the other ones fail? I'll share my assumptions as to why that is, and I'd like you to confirm or reject these assumptions and explain what exactly happens in every scenario.

---

My assumptions as to what happens in each case:

`Shape* rect = Rectangle(5, 5)` creates a `Rectangle` object on the stack (which is where *static* data is allocated..?), and then tries to put it in a `Shape*` pointer. Since `Shape*` is a variable that's supposed to hold the address of a `Shape` object (or subclass), it doesn't make sense to assign it the object itself.

`Shape* rect = &Rectangle(5, 5)` creates a `Rectangle` object on the stack, and then tries to fetch it's address and put it in the pointer. The compiler doesn't allow this because since the object is anonymous, it will be gone the next line (..?), and the address would be irrelevant.

`Shape* rect = new Rectangle(5, 5)` creates a `Rectangle` object on the heap (which is where *dynamic* data is stored..?), and then tries to assign it to the `Shape*` pointer. I don't understand why it works. Pointers store addresses, not objects. Why does it make sense to store an object in a pointer? And since indeed it works, why didn't it work on the first attempt (i.e. `Shape* rect = Rectangle(5, 5)`)?

---

1. If anything I wrote was technically wrong, please say so and explain.
2. Please explain why the working code works and the failing code
   fails.

Comment: Which part of the compiler error message is unclear for you in particular?

Comment: Do you understand what `new` does, and how a pointer differs from an object? If not, review your introductory textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumptions are more or less correct, but the vocabulary
you're using is confusing, and not that common in the C++
community.

For starters, the expression `Rectangle(5, 5)` creates
a *temporary* of type `Rectangle`.  It's on the stack, but the
important thing is that it has temporary lifetime; it will cease
to exist at the end of the full expression.  You'll sometimes
here temporaries referred to as rvalues; it's more or less the
same thing in practice.

And it is *not* static; static data are data that have static
lifetimes, and are not on the stack.

The first statement fails for the reason you (and the compiler)
said: a `Rectangle` is not a `Shape*`.  In fact, it's not
a pointer at all.  It's possible to overload a conversion
operator so that it will implicitly convert to a `Shape*`, but
that's an advanced topic, best left until later.  Otherwise, an
instance of a class type will not convert to a pointer type.

The second statement fails because the language forbids
explicitly taking the address of a temporary.  Your assumption
gives the main motivation, but there *are* still a lot of ways
you can get the address of a temporary and screw up.

The third statement works because the results of a `new T`
expression has the type `T*` (unless `T` is an array
type—but there's never any case where you'd want to `new`
an array type).  A new expression creates a new object whose the
lifetime is dynamic, and returns a pointer to it; in this case,
a `Rectangle*`.  And there *is* an implicit conversion from
`Derived*` to `Base*`.

Objects with dynamic lifetimes are commonly said to live on the
heap.

Comment: @Yakk Because array new is based on C style arrays, which are
more or less broken.  There are valid reasons to use them in
certain contexts, but none where they would have dynamic
storage.  And "automatic storage" is almost always on the stack,
not on the heap, and "free store", as used in the standard, is
the heap.

Comment: @james I am not sure why free store allocated arrays are any more broken than free store allocated anything else.  Sure, you have to keep track of length and lifetime, but the hard part is lifetime, which is common to every other `new` expression.  And before dynarray, the alternative (`std::vector`) had modest overhead (extra pointer) or failed to store length and required `new[]` anyhow (`unique_ptr<T[]>`).  The reasons to use smart storage remain similar for scalars as arrays.  And if you are writing an `any` or similar, you'll probably want to write a custom smart ptr anyhow.  (for sbo)

Comment: @Yakk Because you don't get back a pointer to the type you allocated.  It's the same problem with C style arrays in general.  (And if you're allocating dynamically, it's usually because the lifetime is determined by the program logic, which means not knowing it is more or less the same as not knowing what the program is to do.)

Comment: @James if that is your only problem, then write 4 lines of code that fixes it: http://ideone.com/nHtbLk here we have `nalloc`, which calls `new`, and returns a pointer-to-what-you-actually-allocated (!).  Naturally this only works on compile-time lengths (as types are compile-time determined).

Answer (score 2):

because:

```
Rectangle(5, 5);
```

returns a Rectangle object but

```
new Rectangle(5, 5);
```

returns a pointer to a rectangle object.

If you want to use polymorphism you need to use pointers.

Comment: Ohh, so `new` returns a pointer. Got it. By the way, what's the difference between `Thing t;` and `Thing t = Thing();`? Both create a `Thing` object and put it in variable `t`, right?

Comment: You fail to explain why `Shape* rect = &Rectangle(5, 5);` failed too.

Comment: @AvivCohn In practice, there is little difference: formally, however, `Thing t = Thing();` creates a temporary `Thing`, then copies it to `t`; `Thing t;` creates the object immediately.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks. Two questions regarding that: 1- Does `Thing t = Thing()` create two objects, and than 'overrides' the first one? Or does it only create one? 2- Why would I ever want to do `Thing t = Thing()`?

Comment: You can use polymorphism without pointers.  It isn't very useful, but you can do it with references.

Comment: @AvivCohn In theory: `Thing t = Thing();` creates two objects, one with temporary lifetime, and a second with automatic lifetime, which is made by copying the first.  The first is then destroyed.  In practice, the standard authorizes the compiler to elide the extra temporary, and most, if not all compilers do, so there will be only one object.